# How do I make a trigger that only affects the row that was updated/inserted?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table with two columns where I need one (`columnB`) to be a copy of the other one (`columnA`). So, if a row is inserted or updated, I want the value from `columnA` to be copied to `columnB`.

Here's what I have now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tUpdateColB
ON products
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table
        SET columnB = columnA
    END
```

The problem now is that the query affects all rows, not just the one that was updated or inserted. How would I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a primary key column, `id`,  (and you should have a primary key), join to the `inserted` table (making the trigger capable of handling multiple rows):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tUpdateColB 
ON products 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE table 
        SET t.columnB = i.columnA 
        FROM table t INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.id = i.id
    END
```

But if ColumnB is always a copy of ColumnA, why not create a [Computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) instead?

[Using the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a special `inserted` table available in triggers that will contain the "after" version of rows impacted by an INSERT or UPDATE operation. Similarly, there is a `deleted` table that will contain the "before" version of rows impacted by an UPDATE or DELETE operation.

So, for your specific case:

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.columnB = t.columnA
    FROM inserted i
        INNER JOIN table t
            ON i.PrimaryKeyColumn = t.PrimaryKeyColumn
```