# sql triggers on update/insert

Tags: sql, triggers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server: how do I make a trigger that only affects the row that was updated/inserted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065570/sql-server-how-do-i-make-a-trigger-that-only-affects-the-row-that-was-updated-i)

```
  Table User
  Userid(number)
  is_updated(char)

  Table Version
  Version_number(number)
  userid(number)
```

Now if I insert/update values in version table, I want to update the is_updated column using a triger but how do I fetch the userid of the updated/inserted row for that?

This is first time with triggers can somebody help me

Comment: Can you specify which Database mySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: ANd if you are using SQL Server, don;t forget to write teh trigger to handle mulitple row inserts. BUT @vikram is correct, we cannot help uyou until you tell us what database as trigger code is very differnt depending on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check books online's documentation on the [CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) statement before posting a question like this. A trigger is nothing more than a special stored procedure that inherits two special virtual tables, *inserted* and *deleted*. So try something like this:

```
create trigger dbo.version_TR01
on             dbo.version
for insert, update
as
begin

  --
  -- make sure everybody has a row in the user table
  --
  insert dbo.[user]( user_id , is_updated )
  select i.user_id , 'F'
  from inserted i
  where not exists ( select *
                     from dbo.[user] u
                     where u.user_id = i.user_id
                   )

  --
  -- mark everybody as updated
  --
  update dbo.[user]
  set is_updated = 'T'
  from dbo.[user] u
  join inserted   i on i.user_id = u.user_id

end
```

That should about do it.