# Trigger Locking Table calculating Running Total

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have the following trigger on a table in SQL Server 2012:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateTotals] 
   ON  [dbo].[DEC10assessmentData] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --update list pract test 1 total
    if update (list_practTest1_s1) or update (list_practTest1_s2)
    begin
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_practTest1_total = CAST(list_practTest1_s1 AS decimal(3 , 1)) + CAST(list_practTest1_s2 AS decimal(3 , 1))
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest1_s1) IS NOT NULL 
            and TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest1_s2) IS NOT NULL
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_practTest1_total = NULL
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest1_s1) IS NULL 
            or TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest1_s2) IS NULL
    end

    --update list test 1 total
    if UPDATE (list_test1_s1) or update (list_test1_s2)
    begin
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_test1_total = CAST(list_test1_s1 AS decimal(3 , 1)) + CAST(list_test1_s2 AS decimal(3 , 1))
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test1_s1) IS NOT NULL 
            and TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test1_s2) IS NOT NULL
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_test1_total = NULL
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test1_s1) IS NULL 
            or TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test1_s2) IS NULL
    end

    --update list pract test 2 total
    if update (list_practTest2_s1) or update (list_practTest2_s2)
    begin
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_practTest2_total = CAST(list_practTest2_s1 AS decimal(3 , 1)) + CAST(list_practTest2_s2 AS decimal(3 , 1))
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest2_s1) IS NOT NULL 
            and TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest2_s2) IS NOT NULL
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_practTest2_total = NULL
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest2_s1) IS NULL 
            or TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_practTest2_s2) IS NULL
    end

    --update list test 2 total
    if UPDATE (list_test2_s1) or update (list_test2_s2)
    begin
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_test2_total = CAST(list_test2_s1 AS decimal(3 , 1)) + CAST(list_test2_s2 AS decimal(3 , 1))
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test2_s1) IS NOT NULL 
            and TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test2_s2) IS NOT NULL
        update DEC10assessmentData
        set list_test2_total = NULL
        where 
            TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test2_s1) IS NULL 
            or TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , dbo.DEC10assessmentData.list_test2_s2) IS NULL
    end

    --update read total
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set read_total = ((read_test1_Scaled / 100 * 8) + (read_test2_scaled / 100 * 12)) / 20 * 100
    where
        read_test1_Scaled is not null and read_test2_scaled is not null

    --update read total to null where scores don't exist
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set read_total = NULL
    where
        read_test1_Scaled is null or read_test2_scaled is null

    --update write total
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set writ_total = (CAST(writ_literatureReview as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 4 
                        + CAST(writ_exposition as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 8 
                        + CAST(writ_groupReport as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 8 
                        + cast(writ_synthSummary as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 8 
                        + cast(writ_critEvaluation as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 12) / 40 * 100
    where
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_literatureReview) is not null and
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_exposition) is not null and
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_groupReport) is not null and
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_synthSummary) is not null and
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_critEvaluation) is not null

    --update write total where scores don't exist
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set writ_total = NULL
    where
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_literatureReview) is null or
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_exposition) is null or
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_groupReport) is null or
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_synthSummary) is null or
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , writ_critEvaluation) is null

    --update list total
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set list_total = ((list_test1_scaled / 100 * 8) + (list_test2_scaled / 100 * 12)) / 20 * 100
    where
        list_test1_scaled is not null and list_test2_scaled is not null

    --update list total to null where scores don't exist
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set list_total = NULL
    where
        list_test1_scaled is null or list_test2_scaled is null

    --update speak total
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set speak_total = (cast(speak_groupPres as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 4
                        + CAST(speak_indivPres as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 8
                        + cast(speak_tutorialDiscus as decimal(3,1)) / 100 * 8) / 20 * 100
    where
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , speak_groupPres) is not null and
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , speak_indivPres) is not null and
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , speak_tutorialDiscus) is not null

    --update speak total where scores don't exist to null
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set speak_total = NULL
    where
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , speak_groupPres) is null or
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , speak_indivPres) is null or
        TRY_CONVERT(decimal(3 , 1) , speak_tutorialDiscus) is null

    --update overall score
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set overall_total = (read_total + writ_total * 2 + list_total + speak_total) / 5

    --update rec/not rec's for skills and overall
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set read_rec = t.rec_read, writ_rec = t.rec_writ, list_rec = t.rec_list, speak_rec = t.rec_speak, overall_rec = t.rec_overall
    from dbo.udf_getDEC10RecSkillAndOverall() as t inner join DEC10assessmentData
    on t.studentID = DEC10assessmentData.studentID and t.assessmentLookup = DEC10assessmentData.assessmentLookup

    --update rec/not rec's for final rec
    update DEC10assessmentData
    set final_rec = t.rec_final
    from dbo.udf_getDEC10RecFinal() as t inner join DEC10assessmentData
    on t.studentID = DEC10assessmentData.studentID and t.assessmentLookup = DEC10assessmentData.assessmentLookup

END

GO
```

I am getting a trigger to calculate running totals in a table after updates to other columns in the table. As you can see, there is unfortunately a lot of casting of varchar values, however it does the job except for one issue - locking.

I intermittently get users complaining they can't perform updates and this seems to be because the trigger is locking the table. Is there any way to avoid this and how do I confirm this is what is happening? They are not updating the columns the trigger updates.

I get the following output from two updates that deadlock using Erland Sommarskog's [beta_lockinfo](http://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/beta_lockinfo.html):

```
rsctype locktype lstatus ownertype    waittime spid waittype
KEY         U   WAIT    TRANSACTION     2.192       LCK_M_U 69
DATABASE    S   grant   STW                     69
KEY         X   grant   TRANSACTION             69
OBJECT      IX  grant   TRANSACTION             69
PAGE        IU  grant   TRANSACTION             69
PAGE        IX  grant   TRANSACTION             69
KEY         U   WAIT    TRANSACTION     2.188       LCK_M_U 89
DATABASE    S   grant   STW                     89
KEY         X   grant   TRANSACTION             89
OBJECT      IX  grant   TRANSACTION             89
PAGE        IU  grant   TRANSACTION             89
PAGE        IX  grant   TRANSACTION             89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first advice should probably be not to do use triggers and move the business logic to some other layer.

Your updates affects the whole table, that will probably produce a table lock:

```
update DEC10assessmentData
set overall_total = (read_total + writ_total * 2 + list_total + speak_total) / 5 
etc
```

Why update other rows than the changed one?
[How to work only on the updated row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065570/sql-server-how-do-i-make-a-trigger-that-only-affects-the-row-that-was-updated-i)

For your calculations, [use calculated columns instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300(v=sql.110).aspx).

Do you really need to do all the converting? Can't you fix your data types in your table definition instead?

But if this is something you absolutely have to do with triggers then maybe you could refactor your table so that you don't store the data in the same table but in two. That way the users would be able to update their data and you can update yours.